# Curly braces in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm currently working through Robin Nixon's [Learning PHP, MySQL, Javascript, CSS & HTML5, 4th Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1491949465), and I'm at a part where he explains how to return an array of variables from a function.

The code he used to demonstrate this is:

```
words = fixNames("the", "DALLAS", "CowBoys")

  for(j = 0 ; j < words.length ; ++j)
    document.write(words[j] + "<br>")

  function fixNames()
  {
    var s = new Array()

    for (j = 0 ; j < fixNames.arguments.length ; ++j)
      s[j] = fixNames.arguments[j].charAt(0).toUpperCase() +
             fixNames.arguments[j].substr(1).toLowerCase()

    return s

}
```

When I was writing this code, I wrote it:

```
words = fixNames2("the", "DALLAS", "CowBoys")
    for(j = 0; j < words.length; ++j) {
        document.write(words[j] + '<br>')
    }
    function fixNames2() {
        var s = new Array()
        for(j = 0; j < fixNames2.arguments.length; ++j) {
        s[j] = fixNames2.arguments[j].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + 
                fixNames2.arguments[j].substr(1).toLowerCase()

                return s
        }
}
```

I know in an earlier part of the book, he mentions that you don't need to surround single statements with curly braces, and I thought the second `for` conditional was 2 statements (the `s[j]` part, and the `return s` part), so I surrounded the whole thing with curly braces, but for some reason, when written this way, the code only outputs the first word in the array ('the', but correctly formatted by the function so that it's 'The').

I was wondering if anyone could explain to me why this is? Is it that the 2nd `for` conditional is actually only actually 1 statement? Or does it perhaps have something to do with the way I nested the curly braces?

Comment: Your `return` statement is inside the `for` loop, so only the first iteration of your loop executes before it returns.

Comment: Once you hit the `return` statement, your method is satisfied, so the algorithm ends. If you move it outside the loop, it will function as intended.

Comment: Yes.  The second `for` loop is intended to have only one statement inside it  -- that's why it doesn't use the curly braces.  You changed the program by putting the `return` inside the for loop.

Comment: To touch on the curly braces, the author isn't wrong that you don't *need* them for single statements. However, you *should* still include them. It better shows the flow of your code, and helps prevent unexpected results such as the problem you just ran into.

Comment: You could have easily debugged this problem yourself by stepping through your code in the debugger.

Comment: His uninformed and dangerous comments on semicolons are in themselves a good reason for finding a different book to learn from.

Comment: You could have easily seen the problem yourself by simply indenting and formatting your code properly. Or choosing an editor which does that for you.

Comment: @DrewKennedy: I agree; I think he omits them 1) to demonstrate the flexibility of Javascript, and 2) for brevity's sake. But I agree with most of the comments here: I always learned to end statements with semicolons and bracket conditionals, and while you can do away with them (for single-line statements) in JS, it's reasons like what I just encountered why I prefer them.

Comment: @torazaburo: 1) What's the debugger? Do you mean dev. tools in a browser?

2) He's right about the semicolons. I'll probably still use them for all statements anyway (just so I don't have to switch between "semicolon-mode" for PHP, and "non-semicolon-mode" for JS).

3) Yes, the reason why I messed up the formatting was--as other users stated-- because I was including the `return` statement in the `for` block. But I think it's good to have these kinds of problems. Now, if I encounter something similar in other code, I'll be better prepared to recognize it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "return" is not part of the for loop (it's a part of the function) but you included it within those braces -- so it's not going to work the way the original author intended.

So:

```
 for(j = 0; j < fixNames2.arguments.length; ++j) {
        s[j] = fixNames2.arguments[j].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + 
                fixNames2.arguments[j].substr(1).toLowerCase()

                return s //// WRONG
        }
```

Should be:

```
 for(j = 0; j < fixNames2.arguments.length; ++j) {
        s[j] = fixNames2.arguments[j].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + 
                fixNames2.arguments[j].substr(1).toLowerCase() 
        }
   return s;
```

Or you can even do away with the brackets, since it's just one statement in the for loop:

```
for(j = 0; j < fixNames2.arguments.length; ++j) 
        s[j] = fixNames2.arguments[j].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + 
                fixNames2.arguments[j].substr(1).toLowerCase();

return s;
```

Note that even though it's on two lines it's considered to be one statement as it should end with a semicolon.

Also,

```
s =
x
+
y
+
z;
```

is considered one statement of code. The way to know if something is considered to be a statement is that it's generally ended with a semicolon.

ALWAYS use semicolons to end a statement. It's bad practice not to (even if it runs).

Comment: Ah, so that's what it was. Makes perfect sense now. :) Thanks!